# Quitar el foco de un widget al clicar fuera en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Estoy desarrollando una interfaz gráfica en tkinter y me gustaría poder quitar el foco a un widget al clicar fuera de él, puesto que me parece molesto para el usuario tener siempre un widget seleccionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido! Este código hace lo que buscas. Al hacer clic en cualquier lugar de la ventana donde no haya un widget, el foco se pondrá en la ventana, de manera que cualquier widget será desenfocado.

```
from tkinter import *

v=Tk()
Entry().pack()

def desenfocar(Event):
    #Este condicional revisa que no se haya hecho clic en un widget.
    if(Event.widget == v):
        v.focus()

v.bind("<Button-1>", desenfocar)
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Dante S! Funciona de maravilla